# Effect of changing memory limit

Tags: memory, memory-management, hosting, web-hosting, ram

I have been having trouble with a page crashing on my website and I have worked out that it is because the memory limit is too low. I have read an article (http://codingcyber.com/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit-on-godaddy-hosting-882/#) and decided to buy more RAM and I am about to increase the memory limit.

Before I do, I just want to know what will happen if multiple users are using the site all at once. I guess a clearer way to explain my question is with an analogy.

If I have 2048mb ram and a `memory_limit = 256mb`, what happens if 20 users all login at once and use 50mb of the RAM? I imagine that since no one has exceeded the 256mb limit and the total RAM used (50mb * 20 users = 2000mb) is just under the 2048 limit, that the site should be ok, but I just want to confirm that this is correct (I've never done anything like this before).

Thanks for confirming or correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Just spoke with godaddy and they explained that it's not a problem to have extra people as long as the TOTAL RAM used is lower than the site limit. If one person goes over it will only impact them. If everyone goes over the limit as a whole (unlikely in my case) that's when we will have problems...